# How to find out which executable is invoked when starting a program using the GUI launcher?

Tags: gnome, launcher, 19.04

When running something from the command-line, the `which` command can be used to find out which executable is actually called. That is great. I would like to be able to find out that information also for programs that are started using the graphical launcher.

For example, if I press the super key (the one with a windows logo on it) and start typing "sound", the program "Sound Recorder" pops up and I can click on it to start it. Then it starts, fine, but how do I know which executable it was that I just started? The name is not necessarily the same as the name "Sound Recorder" that I clicked on.

For this example I can figure it out doing some guesswork, like this:

```
ps -A | grep sound
 1848 tty2     00:00:00 gsd-sound
13645 tty2     00:00:00 gnome-sound-rec
```

So it is probably gnome-sound-recorder and then I can do

```
which gnome-sound-recorder
```

to find out it is actually `/usr/bin/gnome-sound-recorder`.

But that was assuming the executable same was something with "sound", what if that was not the case? Is there a better way to find out which executable is launched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the desktop launcher in one of these 2 locations:

- `/usr/share/applications/`
- `~/.local/share/applications`

The Exec line is what is executed so ...

```
grep Exec audacious.desktop
```

(random example) would show

```
 Exec=audacious %U
 TryExec=audacious
```